# Use node as field in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, field, content-type

Is it possible in drupal 7 to use a content type as field in another content type?

For example, I want the user to type some structure information like Address Content Type in Customer Content Type:

```
Name: [    ]
Email [    ]
Address 1: Street[    ], City:[    ], Country [    ]
Address 2: Street[    ], City:[    ], Country [    ]
Address 3: Street[    ], City:[    ], Country [    ]
```

is it possible to create the Address Content Type and use it as a field in Customer Content Type?

Please advice.
Abbas

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [References module](http://drupal.org/project/references)

**Edit:**

If you want to create everything in one go, then look into using the [Field Group module](http://drupal.org/project/field_group) which will allow you to group certain fields together.

Note that this will NOT create Addresses as a content type but rather as fields within the Customer content type.

I don't know of any module that currently exists which will automatically create content types in the way that you've specified.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this module doesn't allow me to fill the content of both Address Content Type and Customer Content Type in my example above.

Comment: I was able to get my desired results by using Field collection
and Field Group module.

Thank you so much